# Why getche() function overwrites input when enter key is pressed?

Tags: c

I used the following codes:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
int main()  
{   
  char ch,a[5];  
  int j=0;   
  while((ch=getche())!='\n')  
  {  
    a[j]=ch;  
    j++;  
  }  
  printf("%c",a[2]);  
  return 0;  
}
```

When I input characters and press <kbd>enter</kbd> key in the end of line, the blinker`s position gets shifted to top-left corner of screen and further characters can be input which will seem to overwrite the pre-existing characters (but doesn't).

Using `ch=getchar()` instead of `getche()` ends the loop and displays the value as intended.Can't I get similar output using `getche()`? Output isn't displayed using `getche()` with `'\n'`. However, using some other characters instead of `'\n'`(e. g. `n`) works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are variation depending on keyboard  and `stdin`, but `getche()` gets the key without echoing.  When the user types <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the un C-ified char may be `'\n'` or `'\r'`.  When this is printed you get the corresponding line-feed or carriage return.  Since <kbd>Enter</kbd> maps to `'\r'` on your keyboard, when fetched via `getche()`, test for that and print `'\n'`.  When fetched via `getchar()`, C translates the <kbd>Enter</kbd> to `'\n'`.

   ```
   int ch = getche();
   if (ch == '\r') c = '\n';
   printf("%c", ch);
   ```
2. Use `int ch` so code can check for EOF.